# Obtener valores de un JSON por individual

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

Teniendo esta función:

```
<script>
    function testAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://dev.datos.ua.es/uapi/5QGUfP3UM6j5VXERjKvU/datasets/11/data', type: 'GET',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    var misdatos = data[i].bbox;                        
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Y en **misdatos**, hay varias longitudes y latitudes:

`"-0.515358212377548,38.3869756882801,-0.514646718387274,38.3874205581019"`,
`"-0.527918228743998,38.3810201755556,-0.526373500350929,38.3822401809516"`,

etc.
Quiero obtener el primer y el segundo valor de cada lsita de 4 elementos, las cuales no son un array de 4 elementos. He probado con un `split(',')` pero no funciona.

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"0008",
         "nombre":"FACULTAD DE CIENCIAS I",
         "bbox":"-0.515358212377548,38.3869756882801,-0.514646718387274,38.3874205581019",
         "count_geometrias":2098,
         "plantas":"{P1,P3,P2,PB,PS}"
      },
      {
         "id":"0206",
         "nombre":"CENTRO INCUBADOR DE EMPRESAS",
         "bbox":"-0.527918228743998,38.3810201755556,-0.526373500350929,38.3822401809516",
         "count_geometrias":250,
         "plantas":"{PB}"
      },
      {
         "id":"0028",
         "nombre":"RECTORADO Y SERVICIOS GENERALES",
         "bbox":"-0.512869386775825,38.3843008776237,-0.51118534833184,38.3851009545756",
         "count_geometrias":525,
         "plantas":"{PB,PS,P1}"
      },
      {
         "id":"0026",
         "nombre":"FACULTAD DE CIENCIAS DE LA SALUD",
         "bbox":"-0.51488946186396,38.3835841864622,-0.514392670169672,38.384200566229",
         "count_geometrias":749,
         "plantas":"{PB,P1}"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el contenido de `data`? para poder ayudarte

Comment: Ya está incorporado

Comment: Modificaste la salida? data deberia ser un array `[]` pero no veo los corchetes

Comment: Si, lleva un corchete al principio [ y otro al final, pero es muy largo. Puedes verlo aqui: https://dev.datos.ua.es/uapi/5QGUfP3UM6j5VXERjKvU/datasets/11/data

Comment: Que yo sepa el dataType debe ser json no jsonp... dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))

Comment: Eso no debe ser un problema, el caso es quitar las comas para obtener un array de latitudes y longitudes

Comment: El split funciona, no veo el problema: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/teyosowuzo/edit?js,console)

Comment: Que, una vez tengo los datos divididos, soy incapaz de obtener una longitud o latitud en concreto.

Comment: Checa este bin: http://jsbin.com/tiyonoquxo/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Está genial ese código, creo que es lo que necesito, pero como lo uso en el body? la idea es meterlo como marcador en un mapa

Comment: Ya publique mi respuesta, en cuanto a lo que mencionas de como insertar los marcadores a tu mapa eso esta fuera de esta pregunta, puedes intentar elaborar tu código de maps y hacer otra pregunta en el sitio.

Comment: Como obtengo solo las dos primeras latitud y longitud?, me aparecen todas de una

Answer (score 1):

Únicamente necesitas hacer un `.split(',')` y acceder a los datos como si fuera un array.

```
function testAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://dev.datos.ua.es/uapi/5QGUfP3UM6j5VXERjKvU/datasets/11/data', type: 'GET',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var coordenadas = item.bbox.split(',');
                console.log('Coordenadas ' + i);
                console.log(coordenadas[0], coordenadas[1], coordenadas[2], coordenadas[3]);
            });
        }
    });
}
```